# BlackBerry Java Media Unsupported

Tags: java, video, blackberry, java-me, codec

I download an MP4 file from the internet and play it on the blackberry device. I get the following error:  "the video portion of the media being played uses an unsupported format". The audio starts playing, but the video doesn't play, while showing this error.

It should be noted that this only happens on Device OS 5 & 6. The same video plays properly or OS 7 and OS 7.1. I am guessing this is because RIM included some updates to MMAPI. What could i do to allow devices prior to OS 7 play the videos? OS 5 & 6 devices play MP4 files, just not all of them.

I have been looking into custom decoding the bytes of the MP4 file, but that will take a lot of time, looking into existing decoder implementation before adapting to J2ME, not an easy task.

Any help would be great here.

---

**Edit:**

The video content owners have control of the videos on the server side, but arent willing to re encode, mainly due to size concerns on the server, even though i recommended they do as well.

The resolution of the video is about 720w x 400h. This is quite high for a BB, but Bold 9790 and Torch 9810 both play it without a problem. So why cant Bold 9780 play the same file?

Comment: Please also clarify which **devices** (not just OS versions) you're having problems with, and whether or not the videos are yours (and can be modified on your server side), or various videos online, that you don't control.  If you can share a link to the problem video itself, that might also be helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: problems with Bold 9780 running OS 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Regarding the problem with the video playing on a 9790 and not a 9780, those are different devices.  The 9790 came out about a year after the 9780, and apparently RIM added more capability.

[From 9780 specs:](http://www.gsmarena.com/blackberry_bold_9780-3431.php)

> - Video player DivX/WMV/XviD/3gp

[From 9790 specs:](http://www.gsmarena.com/blackberry_bold_9790-4332.php)

> - DivX/XviD/MP4/H.264/H.263/WMV player

So, that explains why you can't get that video to play on the 9780.  If playing this video is fundamental to your app, you might change the settings in BlackBerry App World to list it as incompatible with 9780s.  If this is only one of **many** features of your app, you might at least catch the media exception and inform the user gracefully that their device can't play the video requested, *so they don't think it's your app's fault.*

---

**Original Answer:**

[MP4 actually contains a family of related formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG-4_Part_14).

The actual support for your video probably depends **both** on your BlackBerry OS version (e.g. 5/6/7) and also the device itself.

[Here is a BlackBerry reference document](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/smartphone_users/deliverables/27267/Supported_Media_Types_on_BlackBerry_Tablets_%28English%29.pdf) that describes video format capabilities of various BlackBerry devices.

[See also this reference document](https://developer.blackberry.com/devzone/develop/supported_media/bb_media_support_at_a_glance.html#kba1328730952678).

Of course, different devices also have [different sizes of screens](http://www.gsmarena.com/blackberry-phones-36.php).

It might be useful for you to produce the videos in a variety of formats and resolutions, and have your BlackBerry app download different versions of the video depending on the device.  Since video downloads are slow, doing it this way will also ensure that the user sees the fastest possible download on their device.  There's no use downloading a higher resolution than the device can display.

You didn't specify whether you have control of the videos on the server side or not, so this may not be an option for you.

Comment: the content owners have control of the videos on the server side, but arent willing to re encode, mainly due to size concerns on the server, even though i recommended they do as well.

Comment: The resolution of the video is about 720w x 400h. This is quite high for a BB, but Bold 9790 and Torch 9810 both play it without a problem. So why cant Bold 9780 play the same file?

Comment: @Ajibola, as I mentioned, different J2ME/BlackBerry devices do have different multimedia capabilities, and the 9790 is a newer device.  See my update above ... from the gsmarena.com specifications, it looks like the 9780 does not support the video formats you need.

Comment: ok then thanks for the info, especially the doc from RIM. We are exploring re encoding the content.

Comment: I know that's a pain, but sadly, it's probably the best choice at this point :(